# How do I clean paint and glue from bluestone?

Tags: flooring, tile, stone, bluestone

I have Bluestone interior floors in new construction. Ready to finish but slight paint overspray and several glue spots. Is there a problem using a diluted muriatic acid to clean?

Comment: Which type of bluestone do you have? It ranges in toughness from basalt to limestone: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluestone

Comment: What kind of paint?

Comment: Just be sure to test your chosen method on a inconspicuous portion before diving in on your favorite part.

Answer (score 1):

Muriatic could be a bit harsh, causing a 'bleached' spot. Many natural stones are sensitive to acids, most being alkaline (from types of limestone).

A "citrus" paint stripper could be less harsh, but it is acidic, also.

I would use ammonia and a soft nylon hand brush, alternating after rinses with a mild detergent.